# (Volley) Signature uses an insecure hash function

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a little problem with Volley. I'm trying to get the response from some url which is fully working on mobile browser.

Meanwhile in my application I'm getting an error:

> ERROR: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Signature uses an insecure hash function

Is there a way to solve it in an application or should I contact with my backend provider?

Comment: Updating date-time of the device fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little digging and found that:

> Google is now blacklisting weak hash functions in SSL certs and throwing exceptions when trying to communicate with the problem server. Whereas before, it was silently ignored.

[Source](https://plus.google.com/110888727511088340106/posts/fVLQ7bt1GtP)

With that in mind, you could try doing [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa) to teach [HttpsURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) to trust a specific set of CAs.

But in the end, I believe that its your backend providers fault in providing a insecure hash function. So, before trying a huge workaround maybe contacting your backend provider would be the easier way out.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks alot, i think that's correct and final answer!