# android app not connecting to server after renewing ssl

Tags: java, android, nginx, ssl, mobile

The android app stops connecting to the server after installing a new ssl. The ssl was bought from godaddy. It was working perfectly when I used the current ssl, but it's about to expire so I installed the new ssl. I don't think there was a problem when installing the ssl. I included the intermediate cert (gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt) but still the problem exists.

Here is the error that I am getting from the mobile app: (log from logcat).

```
OkHttpClient: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unacceptable certificate: OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority, O="The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", C=US W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Signature uses an insecure hash function:
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this not just a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766380/volley-signature-uses-an-insecure-hash-function

Comment: if android is detecting this is a weak hash, it's probably a bigger issue than just trying to fix it for your app, so not sure this is an android issue, probably something you have to resolve with your certificate

Comment: @local_nobody thanks for the input. What we don't wanna do is fix our app.